# Node.js Zoom API: invalid authorization code

Tags: node.js, zoom-sdk

I have an application that I use to connect the user to the Zoom MarketPlace, according to this guide: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/auth/oauth

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a guy from the Zoom API technical support on the Zoom developer forum, he said:
"My apologies for the delay here, the authorization code will expire in 5 minutes which is why you’re seeing this issue after a 10 minute delay.

Let me know if that helps.

Thanks,
Max"

https://devforum.zoom.us/t/node-js-zoom-api-invalid-authorization-code/55937/4
That's explain my issue. I ended up changing the logic to fetch the token immediately when the user redirect back to my site.